# How to store string from struct into a 2D array

Tags: c

Say I have `char Name[100][20]` and a struct `text` with the `char` variable `name1`. I have a txt file that contains a name and for which I used `sscanf` to store it to `text.name1`. Now I want to store that string into the first row of the 2D array so I did `Name[0][20]={"%s",text.name1};` but it results to an error that says `expected expression before '{' token`.
Can someone please tell me how to fix this :(

Comment: It would be better to post the code instead of describing the code. If it's correct that `name1` is a `char`, you have big problems... BTW: To copy strings in C use `strcpy`

Comment: Please show the code you have so far. And tell us what doesn't work or which problem you have.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, copy&paste the code and format it as a code block. (For the formatting you can use the `{}` tool of the editor field.)

Comment: `{"%s",text.name1}` looks like some shorthand from a different language... maybe Ruby? this isn't C code. In C you might want to copy the string `strcpy` or the memory `memcpy`...

Answer (score 1):

With `Name[0][20]={"%s",text.name1};` you're trying to initialize the array.
However, `{"%s",text.name1};` is not a valid array initializer. To copy text into an array, you can use something like `memcpy()`, or [`sprintf()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/):

```
sprintf(Name[0], "%s", text.name1);
```

Comment: Why use `sprintf` when we have `strcpy` ?

Comment: I tried that and it resulted in like a buffer overflow when running :(

Comment: "in like a" : how sure are you about the problem being a buffer overflow? You could try `strcpy` like 4386427 pointed out, or if the string isn't null-terminated `memcpy(Name[0], text.name1, 20);` 20 is the amount of bytes being copied. In your question you set this value to be 20, so I just used that.